# Contenteditable with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, contenteditable, angular-directive

I am using a contenteditable directive (code out of this discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/528) to allow my model to be updated. I want to update on the backend as well though (I'm using `ngResource`).

My template is loops through `person in people` and for each person:

```
<span contenteditable ng-model="person.name" ng-blur="updatePersonName(person)">{{person.name}}</span>
```

I would have thought that person would be an updated variable on `blur` but when I `console.log` person in `updatePersonName` I get weird output:

```
Resource {id: 1, name: "Bob the Builder", created_at: "2015-04-23T14:57:28.999Z", updated_at: "2015-04-28T11:42:05.701Z", $$hashKey: "object:4"…}
 $$hashKey: "object:4"
 created_at: "2015-04-23T14:57:28.999Z"id: 1
 name: "Bob the Builder With Modifications"
 updated_at: "2015-04-28T11:42:05.701Z"
 __proto__: Resource
```

Note the difference between the names (the second part of this output is the expanded view)

The directive uses:

```
element.bind("blur", function() {
    scope.$apply(read);
});
```

When I call `update` on my `Person` resource, it sends the original model but then seems to update the model locally so that if I make another modification it sends my first change and lags one iteration behind.

Comment: usual order is ng-blur >> blur, so try $timeout(..., 0) in updatePersonName

Comment: is there not a better way to just let `updatePersonName` fire in the right order?

Comment: hmm, ng-change should be right way as it triggers after model changes

Comment: suggest you create a demo. Also that discussion looks failry old, there are a number of directive repos you can try

Comment: @PetrAveryanov ahh - if it only fires on model change (not like javascripts `onChange` event) then that'll work...

Comment: @PetrAveryanov if you write that up as an answer, I'll accept... It is working. Thank you!

Comment: @charlietfl check the last dates in that discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @PetrAveryanov's comment, the problem is that `ng-blur` fires before the model has changed (hence the strange output). `ng-change`, however, fires only once the model has been updated (unlike javascript's `change` event). S the solution was simply:

```
<span contenteditable ng-model="person.name" ng-change="updatePersonName(person)">{{person.name}}</span>
```